# Possible to save winner history winner-ring-alist in savehist or desktop-save to save across sessions

Tags: window, frames, desktop, auto-save, history-variables

I added in the following command to my `.emacs` but it doesn't seem to work:

`(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'winner-ring-alist)`

Is there a way to get the winner-undo history to save across emacs sessions with either `savehist` or `desktop-save`?

Comment: I'm not certain, but the `frameset.el` functionality could probably facilitate this?  I would imagine that you'd need to map over the winner data to generate a save-able version of each configuration, and do the inverse when restoring.

Comment: @phils Okay thanks! I'll look into that.